# Where is Android Emulator Internal Storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

I have an error due to the contents of a file stored in internal storage on my Android Emulator. (I wrote it to file). Is there a way I can view the internal storage used by my app in windows?

I've searched through my whole project folder, sdk, workspace etc and cant find anything. I saw someone in another question say it was in the /data folder, but i dont know where to look for that either.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to view the folder/file structure of the running emulator, you can do that with the Android Device Monitor which is included with the SDK.

Specifically, it has a File Explorer, which allows you to browse the folder structure on the device. It also has buttons which give you the adb push/pull functionality but from a GUI if this is easier for you to use.

Comment: From Eclipse: Click Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS.

Comment: Great thanks. Can you actually open the files from there or just see that they exist?

Comment: You should be able to grab them off the emulator using the adb pull command. There is a button for it in the File Exporer view. Looks like a floppy disk :)

Comment: Might be a good idea to acclimatise yourself with using `adb` via a terminal/command prompt as it's much easier/faster once you get the hang of it. The DDMS however is a very useful tool and quite powerful for troubleshooting all sorts of issues.

Comment: Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2. Details here -> https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

Answer (score 14):

In Android Studio on Mac you can go to `View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer`. Here you can use a finder-like structure.

Comment: this must've been removed from Studio recently. Unfortunately it's not an option under  `Tool Windows` in Hedgehog | 2023.1.1. It only has `Device Explorer` and `Device Manager`.

Answer (score 6):

They are stored in an img file inside the avd directory.  If you are using Linux you can mount the img file via:

```
sudo mount -o loop ~/.android/avd/<youremulator>/sdcard.img <mountpoint>
```

Not sure if there is a way in Windows or Mac to view the contents of the img since they are either in ext3, ext4, or yaffs file system format (depending on what you are emulating) and windows doesn't easily support those file systems.

Your best bet is to use adb to copy the file directly out of the emulator while it is running as shown in adb --help:

```
adb pull <remote> [<local>]  - copy file/dir from device
```

Comment: I'm not too great with command line, I tend to use Eclipse for everything but thanks for the help :) If theres a way i can do this programatically that would be useful

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio 3.2 and later you can access a device's internal storage by using the menu item

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer
```

See this article for details: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer

...and this one to find out where the other components of Android Device Monitor ended up: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

Comment: this must've been removed from Studio recently. Unfortunately it's not an option under  `Tool Windows` in Hedgehog | 2023.1.1. It only has `Device Explorer` and `Device Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

In `Android N` emulator you can easily get access Internal Memory.

Go to Emulator:

Settings -> Memory -> Internal Storage -> Others

Then a pop up will open. Click on `explore`. Then you will get access of Internal Storage.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Hedgehog (2023.1.1 Patch 2) you can find it under the Device Manager menu. Just click the three dots and you will find the Option "Show on Disk".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

in Android Studio 4.1 and later you can access a device's internal storage by using the menu item

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer -> storage
```