# Reading file from C drive from Android Emulator

Tags: android

I am trying out a test application on an Android emulator.  I would like the app to write data to a file that is stored on my C drive. I have read and written data off Samba drives and webservices, but reading and writing to my local hard seems to be a puzzle.  I tried `filePath = "file:///C:/test/input/";` to point it as my parent folder, but the Emulator doesn't seem to recognize the directory, and I get a 'not found' error.

Any ideas will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Which emulator are you using?

Comment: ADT on Eclipse 4.2.2

Comment: Thank you very much guys.  I am going to do some homework based on all your inputs.  Worst case scenario, I'll mark CommonsWare's as the answer and I'll cook up a webservice.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like the app to write data to a file that is stored on my C drive.

That is not possible, unless that file is accessible via some server. The Android SDK emulator does not have access to the filesystem of the developer PC.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are using an android emulator I am guessing it is setting up some special folder to act as a proxy for the androids hard drive. Meaning that the android emulator doesn't understand what your C drive is and instead is looking in it's 'hard drive' for a file. Find out where the emulator puts files for android, it could be  a temp folder, and store your file there.

Edit: [Where is Android Emulator Internal Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729032/where-is-android-emulator-internal-storage) this question should help you find where the files should be stored and the naming conventions.

Comment: Great answer! +1 because I didn't know you can do that with the bundled emulator. I don't think it will help the author though, because he needs to access his external drive from the emulated device. Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think that is what he needs to do.... If I understand it correctly it seems like he is just using his c drive because it's an emulator. If you wanted to access an external drive with android that is probably a different question altogether.

Comment: "I would like the app to write data to a file that is stored on my C drive" ?

Comment: "I have read and written data off Samba drives and webservices, but reading and writing to my local hard seems to be a puzzle." That line suggested to me that he was just trying to use a local hard drive, not any specific hard drive but just a local one, and not a cloud drive, but now I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care using [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator instead you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card) answer, pointing to [this post](https://plus.google.com/111561249038747241670/posts/d2ogLdU1rZw), it has just what you need